# Does requestFullScreen() only work for width and relative position?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm programming something with canvas and want to add fullscreen support. I found the API and its working but with some problems:

First of all I recognized that fullscreen mode uses the full width of the monitor. But my canvas element is a square so not all is of the height is displayed on a 16:9 monitor. Is it possible to fullscreen according to the height of an element?

Another problem is that fullscreen does not seem to support absolute positioned elements. My code looks like this:

```
<div id="canvasWrapper" style="positon: relative;">
    <p><button ng-click="fullscreen()">Go Fullscreen</button></p>
    <canvas id="bgCanvas" style="position: absolute; border: 1px #E5E5E5 solid;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="position: absolute; border: 1px #E5E5E5 solid;"></canvas>
</div>
```

This codes enables multiple layers for my canvas. But when I fullscreen the div "canvasWrapper" the resulting screen is centered and very small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to fullscreen according to the height of an element?

No, the full-screen mode does not care about the proportion of the element it initiates from - it will use the *screen* dimensions as target.

You will need to handle this in code by padding the edges.

> Another problem is that fullscreen does not seem to support absolute positioned elements.

The [specifications](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-element-requestfullscreen) doesn't say anything about this as far as I could see just browsing over it. However, the full-screen mode has currently an experimental status in most major browsers and the behavior can vary from browser to browser as well as being unstable and prone to bugs.

From [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode):

> It's worth noting a key difference here between the Gecko and WebKit
>   implementations at this time: Gecko automatically adds CSS rules to
>   the element to stretch it to fill the screen: "width: 100%; height:
>   100%". WebKit doesn't do this; instead, it centers the fullscreen
>   element at the same size in a screen that's otherwise black. To get
>   the same fullscreen behavior in WebKit, you need to add your own
>   "width: 100%; height: 100%;" CSS rules to the element yourself [...]
>   On the other hand, if you're trying to emulate WebKit's behavior on
>   Gecko, you need to place the element you want to present inside
>   another element, which you'll make fullscreen instead, and use CSS
>   rules to adjust the inner element to match the appearance you want.

If you haven't already you should check result in different browsers to see if the behavior you are experiencing differs or is the same.